# How can I return context sensitive return values in Perl 6?

Tags: raku, perl

In the summary of [differences](http://perlcabal.org/syn/Differences.html#wantarray%28%29_is_gone) between Perl 5 and Perl 6, it is noted that the `wantarray` function is gone:

> wantarray() is gone
>
> wantarray is gone. In Perl 6, context
>   flows outwards, which means that a
>   routine does not know which context it
>   is in.
>
> Instead you should return objects that
>   do the right thing in every context.

Could someone provide an example of how such an object is created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think 2 examples might be:

---

http://perlcabal.org/syn/S13.html#Type_Casting

> A class may define methods that allow it to respond as if it were a routine, array, or hash. The long forms are as follows:

```
method postcircumfix:<( )> ($capture) {...}
method postcircumfix:<[ ]> (**@slice) {...}
method postcircumfix:<{ }> (**@slice) {...}
```

> Those are a bit unwieldy, so you may also use these short forms:

```
method &.( $capture ) {...}
method @.[ **@slice ] {...}
method %.{ **@slice } {...}
```

---

Also, I think this might be relevant though less so: http://perlcabal.org/syn/S12.html

Search for:

> You may write your own accessors to override any or all of the autogenerated ones.

So you return an object which has several context-specific accessors.

---

Interestingly enough, it started out with Perl6 replacing "wantarray" with a generic "want": [RFC 98 (v1) context-based method overloading, circa 2000](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.language.subs/2000/08/msg55.html), also at http://dev.perl.org/perl6/rfc/21.html . I'm not sure why/when the change was made.

Answer (score 3):

This [comment](http://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/dr8z4/perl_6_immutable_sigils_and_context/) on Reddit about the blog post [Immutable Sigils and Context](http://perlgeek.de/blog-en/perl-6/immutable-sigils-and-context.html) gives the following examples:

```
class GeoLocation is Array {
    method Str { 'middle of nowhere' }
}

sub remote_location {
    return GeoLocation.new(1e6 xx 3);
}

# or even easier:

sub remote_location {
    return (1e6 xx 3) but 'middle of nowhere';
}
```